# Add mp3 files in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created a countdown app and I want when the time is equal to 0 for a sound to play.
I've already imported a plugin for that which is the audioplayers plugin, but when I want to play the song I add in the assets folder on my pubsec.yaml it doesn't work.

Here my pubsec with the sound in mp3:

```
  assets:
- stuffandmore/Logo.png
- stuffandmore/panda.png
- stuffandmore/quoteimg.png
- stuffandmore/Lwolf.jpg
- stuffandmore/Lfarm.jpg
- stuffandmore/ring.mp3
```

And here the code :

```
   else{
     _timer!.cancel();
     print("The music is playin'");
     audioCache.load("stuffandmore/ring.mp3");
     audioCache.play("stuffandmore/ring.mp3");
   }
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: 1) Whether you are getting any error? 2) The indentation in the pubspec file correct? 3) Did you check the volume on your device?

Comment: There should be an indent below assets, check the docs here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your assets directory correctly.
In my case: **"assets/sounds/correct.mp3"**

[image]

If you don't have subdirectory, just write :  **audioCache.load("assets/stuffandmore/ring.mp3");**

And please be sure you have correctly added your mp3 file in the assets folder.

Comment: It is not explicitly necessary to have an "assets" folder.

Comment: but it's mentioned in the question:  assets folder. So it's a needed must.